# PHP 301 Redirect - collect referrer

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm doing a 301 redirect on site A to site B - when the user arrives at site B it needs to find the page the user came from. This doesn't seem to be working though:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

whereas if I do a link to the page

```
<a href="http://site-b.com">go</a>
```

I get the referrer through. Is there a reason it doesn't come through after the redirect? If so can anyone offer any advice on how to do this. I want to avoid at all costs having a query string on the redirect.

Is there maybe another header I need to send with the page that redirects?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, the `HTTP_REFERER` is site A. That's just how a 301 works.

That said, the easy way to do this is to take the url of the referrer to site A onto the end of site B's URL as a variable. Then, at site B, any time you have a referral from site A, you can have it.

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://site-b.com/?ref="
            .urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']),TRUE,301);
?>
```

Then of course at site B, access `urldecode($_GET['ref'])` for your referrer.

However... if you're looking to avoid `_GET`  variables, you have a few options.

**A)** Collect the `_GET` request, then re-munge the URL -- IE have site B redirect to a "clean" version of itself.

**B)** Have your redirecting page make a `curl` or `stream_get_contents` over to a "collection" page prior to issuing a `header()`, where you collect and store the any session information (like the refererer) and have it prepared to be processesed when they redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a CGI query string to the end of your URL when doing the redirect -- eg

```
http://www.site-b.com?redirectfrom=www.site-a.com
```

site-b.com would ignore the URL parameter, but it would be recorded in the logs and would be accessible from within PHP.

Comment: The original poster says that he wants to avoid query strings at all costs so I don't think this will be what they're after

Comment: yes, query string isn't really an option, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it with javascript. Use the following script, but it between <head> and </head>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
location.href='http://www.site-b.com';
</script>
```

This will of course not make a proper HTTP 301 redir, but I just tested it, and it will send the referer (the referer being site-a).